# AlertDialog hyperlink not clickable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a alertdialog that contains a hyperlink, however the hyperlink isn't clickable. It does show as a hyperlink

```
    val termsDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
    val termsView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.termsdialog, null)
    val termsBox: CheckBox = termsView.findViewById(R.id.termsCheckbox)
    val termsMsg = Html.fromHtml("By using this application you accept to our Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy. \nMore information <a href=\"https://mylink.com\">here</a>")

    termsDialog.setTitle("Terms and Conditions")
    termsDialog.setView(termsView)
    termsDialog.setMessage(termsMsg)
    termsDialog.setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ -> }
    termsDialog.setCancelable(false)

    termsBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, _ ->
        if (compoundButton.isChecked) {
            storeDialogStatus(true)
        } else {
            storeDialogStatus(false)
        }
    }

    // Automatic show terms dialog when dialog status is not checked
    if (!this.getDialogStatus()) {
        termsDialog.show()
    }
```

[image: The word here is a hyperlink]

Comment: Yes indeed. It shows it. You cannot expect more from a title of such a box. It is not a WebView. Use a WebView or something else that catches the click. You cant put that html string on any TextView but the TextView will not handle the link. But.. you can catch the click..

Comment: yes I did this and works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a TextView for your message in `termsdialog.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you must call `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())` on your `TextView`:

```
val termsDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
val termsView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.termsdialog, null)
val termsMessage: TextView = termsView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_textview)
val termsMsg = Html.fromHtml("By using this application you accept to our Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy. \nMore information <a href=\"https://mylink.com\">here</a>")

termsDialog.setTitle("Terms and Conditions")
termsDialog.setView(termsView)
termsMessage.setText(termsMsg)
termsMessage.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())
termsDialog.show()
```

Comment: Thanks this also worked. However the \n newline doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: @mohammed_sajid use '<br>' instead of '\n'.